# p5.js Loading texture onto 2D ellipse

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am looking to make a cloud particle system with P5.js. I intend to have many ellipses with PNG cloud texture fill. Then program a system with these ellipses.

Unfortunately I am getting an error when I try to apply the texture in p5.js

Uncaught TypeError: this._renderer._getShader is not a function

```
var cloudImg;

//P5 Setup
function setup(){
    createCanvas(1500, 750);
    background('rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)');
    cloudImg = loadImage("cloud100.png"),
    numParts = 80,
    diam = 100;
}


//Render
function draw(){
    background(0);
    translate(mouseX, mouseY);
    beginShape();
    texture(cloudImg);
    var theta = TWO_PI / numParts;
    for (i=0; i<numParts; i++) {
    var angle = theta * i,
        x = cos(angle),
        y = sin(angle);
    vertex(x * diam, y * diam, (x+1)/2, (y+1)/2);
    }
    endShape();
}
```

Comment: What line throws the error? Have you tried using the [preload()](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) function?

Comment: It was a line in p5.min.js ...I'll have to take a look at preload

Answer (score 0):

I think `texture()` need `webgl` as the render.

Try `createCanvas(1500, 750, WEBGL);`

Click [here](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/texture) to see the offical document of `texture()`.